# How to list files of any installed app in the MAC programmetically?

Tags: macos, mac, applescript

I am making MAC app in which I want to list of files / folders related to any installed app in the mac.

For example;

I want to get list of all the files and folders of Skype app installed in my MAC programmatically.

How can I do this?

Can I get list of files or folder related to installed mac programatically?

Comment: Simply no  -- there is no standard

Comment: Define "any installed app".

Answer (score 2):

There are three ways to do this:

- pay for or find people to install every possible app in a controlled environment and create a database of files and app versions
- make code to patrol the file system and catalog changes and try to piece apart which changes resulted from which app install
- pray all app developers use either the App Store distribution method or write an installation package receipt with a .bom file

Practically, none of these options is easy. The penalty of bad patrol code is worse than whatever problem you may be trusting to solve. The rest have miserable coverage or onerous errors and costs.

Answer (score -1):

Try using this command : `mdfind -name "Your app name"`